# How to pass variable in find() method in mongo db using python

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

```
   TPID=[318,205,2624,2635]
   Tid= len(TPID)
    try:
        mclient = MongoClient(host="tgl-mongodb22.rctanalytics.com", port=27017)
        Db = mclient['sitereft4']
        Db.authenticate('st_sitereference', 'rlQ2YnPKNlS0')
        coll = Db['shopper_journey_sitedata']
        for i in range(Tid):
            data = coll.find({"third_party_site_id":318})
            for datas in data:
                None
        print(datas["st_site_id"])
```

In place of 318 i need to pass the variable **"Tid"** so that it should run for all values.
how to do it ?
i tried below one it didn't worked:
**data = coll.find({"third_party_site_id":Tid[i]})**

Comment: I tried that too, its not working.

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to find each site id in `TPID=[318,205,2624,2635]`

Structure the for loop logic as:

```
for i in TPID:
    data = coll.find({"third_party_site_id":i})
    print(data)
```